# How to resolve source for WiX bootstrapper that is no longer available

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.11

I have a WiX-based installer with a managed bootstrapper application. I'm working on testing an upgrade scenario, where an older package should be uninstalled as part of the upgrade. When the upgrade installer runs the older installer in silent uninstall mode, the uninstall fails with this error:

```
[0970:1AF4][2022-08-05T15:34:49]w341: Prompt for source of container: WixAttachedContainer, path: E:\Bootstrapper.exe
[0970:1AF4][2022-08-05T15:34:49]e054: Failed to resolve source for file: E:\Bootstrapper.exe, error: 0x80070002.
[0970:1AF4][2022-08-05T15:34:49]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed while prompting for source (original path 'E:\Bootstrapper.exe').
[0970:1AF4][2022-08-05T15:34:49]e311: Failed to acquire container: WixAttachedContainer to working path: C:\Windows\Temp\{334EB64E-1CAB-493F-B288-B4FF3EEE53A0}\2DED080EB63A85A0F4732ACF383347EACF8C9909, error: 0x80070002.
[0970:2DB4][2022-08-05T15:34:49]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[22E8:1BE8][2022-08-05T15:34:49]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{85f6f153-1c67-4f5c-84ae-c175c76233be}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: Yes
```

and later in the log:

```
[0970:2DB4][2022-08-05T15:34:49]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = E:\Bootstrapper.exe
```

When I installed the older version, the installer was in an ISO mounted as a virtual drive (E:). That ISO is no longer mounted, which seems to be causing the error here.

I've found [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309118/managed-bootstrapper-failed-while-prompting-for-source) with a similar situation, but the top answer doesn't seem like it would work for me because it suggests setting the `WixBundleOriginalSource` value as the local source for the package. Since that variable is set to a path that no longer exists, I don't think that's what I want to do, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually realized that the issue was that I was re-using the same cache IDs on the `ExePackage`s in my bundle from the previous version. I'm not using auto-generated cache IDs for the packages because several of them share the same source file and payloads. Generating a new GUID for each `CacheId` seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run the original bundle and it will definitely recognize that it is already installed. Then you should be able to uninstall or repair.

Note, there *should* have been a prompt to let you browse to the original bundle from the install UI.

Comment: Sure, I can uninstall the old bundle from the Windows apps and features settings panel, or by re-running the original bundle by mounting the ISO again. But I need the new bundle version to be able to uninstall the old bundle as part of the upgrade.

I probably didn't see a prompt since the uninstaller is running in silent mode.

Comment: Ahh, then I think the real question is: Why is the old bundle prompting for source during upgrade? The log file will show you that and it could be the old bundle has a flaw. Or perhaps, the old bundle got corrupted and needs to be repaired to get upgraded correctly. Or something else. The log file will show you the way.